# How to retrieve the values from nsmutabledictionary

Tags: iphone, nsmutabledictionary

I have stored the data in nsmutabledictionary, given below the dictionary values 
which I stored and the values are the instances, how do I retrieve the values in the object?

```
English =     (
    "<Row: 0x4e50560>",
    "<Row: 0x4e50790>",
    "<Row: 0x4e509d0>"
);
Roman =     (
    "<Row: 0x4e50c60>",
    "<Row: 0x4e50ea0>"
);
japanese =     (
    "<Row: 0x4e51150>",
    "<Row: 0x4e513a0>",
    "<Row: 0x4e515e0>",
    "<Row: 0x4e51860>"
);
arab =     (
    "<Row: 0x4e50140>"
);
```

While I retrieving it, the last object is viewed & I can't view the other object in my code. How do I access the values in the each key of the dictionary and the values are as object. Can anyone explain what I am missing in the above code.

Here is my code

```
NSArray *keys;
    id key, value;

    keys = [appDelegate.viewDictionary allKeys];
    int count = [keys count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        key = [keys objectAtIndex: i];
        value = [appDelegate.viewDictionary objectForKey: key];
        NSLog (@"Key: %@ for value: %@", key, value);
        for(Row *rs in value) {
            NSLog(@"%@", rs.user);
            //cell.textLabel.text = rs.user;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example close to your question, look at the code for differences and see if it helps.

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
       @"<Row: 0x4e50560>",
       @"<Row: 0x4e50790>",
       @"<Row: 0x4e509d0>",
       nil], @"English",

      [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
       @"<Row: 0x4e50c60>",
       @"<Row: 0x4e50ea0>",
       nil], @"Roman",

      [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
       @"<Row: 0x4e51150>",
       @"<Row: 0x4e513a0>",
       @"<Row: 0x4e515e0>",
       @"<Row: 0x4e51860>",
       nil], @"Japanese",

      [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
       @"<Row: 0x4e50140>",
       nil], @"Arab",

      nil];


for (NSString *key in dict) {
    NSArray *value = [dict objectForKey:key];
    NSLog (@"Key: %@ for value: %@", key, value);
    for(NSString *rs in value) {
        NSLog(@"%@", rs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks cocoaFu, when i print in log the result is my dictionary. then the dictionary i got thru dynamically. how to make the dictionary as ur dict. i need some more information.

Comment: I just created a dictionary programmatically for testing, how you get it depends, it could be by reading a plist, obtaining JSON over the Internet and converting to a dictionary or some other method. Perhaps that might be best as another question with more information about the data.

Comment: i got the dictionary from parsing the xml file and converting to dictionary. using this dictionary i need to display the values in grouped tableview. the objects in the dictionary are the instance of class.in my code i displays the last value in the dictionary. i hav a doubt, i am storing the dictionary from two diff. array in array it was stored as arab, english, Roman and japanese. but in dictionary it stored like english, roman, japanese and arab...is this possible..

Answer (score 0):

Does 'allKeys' give you the reference to the actual array, containing the objects (keys)? Try to allocate memory for your "keys" array:

```
keys = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[appDelegate.viewDictionary allKeys]];
```